# AngularJS(ui-router) and dynamically linked scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i have one problem. I use AngularJS with ui-router. So.... i write this states with dynamically named controllers:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    function getURL ($stateParams){
        return "module/" + $stateParams.path;
    }

    function getCtrl ($stateParams){
        var url = $stateParams.path.split("/");
        alert(url [url.length - 1] + "Ctrl");
        return url [url.length - 1] + "Ctrl";
    }
    $urlRouterProvider.when('' , '/#');

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url : "/",
        views : {
            '' : {
                templateUrl : '/resources/template/indexTemplate.html'
            }
        }
    }).state('modules',{
        url : '/{path:.*}',
        views : {
            '' : {
                templateUrl : getURL,
                controllerProvider : getCtrl
            }
        }
    });


});
```

I have one simple controller in file user.js

```
model.controller("userCtrl" , function ($scope) {$scope.user = "fsdfdg";});
```

if i simple include this file in index.html it work great`<script src="user.js"></script>`.
But i get location scripts file from server by http request 
`$http.get("/scripts").success(function(data){
        $scope.scripts = data;
    });`

And when i generate including script `<script ng-repeat="script in scripts" ng-src="{{script}}"></script>` UserController It does not work any more.
Thanks for helping)